Doubts about basics of spinor and Clifford bundles
I'm studying gauge theory and remained baffled in front of my professor's notes. Starting with some definitions
Let E be an oriented vector bundle endowed with a metric with signature (p,q). Let $P_{Spin}$ be a Spin(p,q) structure on E. Let $\mu : Spin(p,q) \rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation of the spin group on arbitrary vector space, obtained from a restriction of a representation of $Cl^{even}(p,q)$. The spinor bundle is defined as the vector bundle associated with the Spin(p,q) structure: $S(E) = P_{Spin} \times_\mu V$.
Here I don't understand why the representation is required to be a restriction from $Cl^{even}(p,q)$. But let's go on to define the Clifford bundle.
Let E be an oriented vector bundle endowed with a metric with signature (p,q). Let $P_{SO}$ be a SO(p,q) structure on E. Let $\rho: SO(p,q) \rightarrow Aut(Cl(p,q))$ be the representation induced by the standard action of SO(p,q) over $R^{p+q}$ on the Clifford algebra. The Clifford bundle on E is then defined as $Cl(E) = P_{SO} \times_\rho Cl(p,q)$.
I have no issue with this one. But then my professor stated that the space of sections of S(E) is a module over the space of sections of Cl(E). This makes little sense to me since we have no action of Cl(p,q) on V. Also, in order to prove it, he presented this diagram with no explanation
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
P_{Spin} \times Cl(p,q) \times V @> \mu >> P_{Spin} \times V \\
@V \rho_g VV @VV \rho'_g V \\
P_{spin} \times Cl(p,q) \times V @> \mu >> P_{Spin} \times V
\end{CD}
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
(q, a, v) @>>> (q, av) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
(qg, g^{-1}ag, g^{-1}v) @>>> (qg, g^{-1}av)
\end{CD}
I have no idea what I'm looking at.

An element of $P_\text{spin}\times\text{Cl}(p,q)\times V$ can locally be written as a tuple $(q,a,v)$. The diagram tells you that that the multiplication map $m:\text{Cl}(E)\times S(E)\to S(E)$ is defined locally as
$[(q,a,v)]\mapsto [(q, av)]$, where $av$ is pointwise Clifford multiplication $\text{Cl}(p,q)\times\mathbb{R}^{p,q}\to\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$. I have written square brackets around the tuples because they are equivalence classes of elements in $P_\text{spin}\times\text{Cl}(p,q)\times V$ and $P_\text{spin}\times V$, respectively. This equivalence is what's expressed by the vertical arrows in the diagram. Two elements in $P_\text{spin}\times V$ are equivalent if and only if
$$(q,v)=(qg,g^{-1}v)$$
for some $g\in\text{Spin}(p,q)$.  In particular, this holds true when substituting $av$ for $v$. Note that this is just the definition of the associated bundle.
Two elements in $P_\text{spin}\times\text{Cl}(p,q)\times V$ are equivalent if and only if
$$(q,a,v)=(qg, g^{-1}ag,g^{-1}v)$$
for some $g\in\text{Spin}(p,q)$. This is the same as before, except it now also tells us how to transform $a$, namely as $a\mapsto g^{-1}ag$. This is no surprise as $v\mapsto g^{-1}v$ by definition, and we want $a\mapsto a'$ where $a'$ is such that $a'g^{-1}v=g^{-1}av$ (i.e. we want the diagram to commute). Therefore, we should choose $a'=g^{-1}ag$.
As for why the representation should be obtained from a representation of $\text{Cl}^0(p,q)$, the even part: we have $\text{Spin}(p,q)\subset\text{Cl}^{0}(p,q)$, and we typically want to be able to talk about Clifford multiplication on the bundle associated to a $\text{Spin}(p,q)$ bundle. That's what makes it interesting, otherwise it would be just a vector bundle. So there must be some consistency between the representation $\rho:\text{Spin}(p,q)\to\text{GL}(V)$ and Clifford multiplication. Thus, we should impose that $\rho$ is a restriction of an algebra representation of $\text{Cl}^0(p,q)$, as this defines both a representation of $\text{Spin}(p,q)$, and ensures we have a bundle of Clifford algebras over which the associated spin bundle is a module.

So this "Clifford multiplication" is the action via a representation of the whole Clifford algebra on V that must be compatible with the one of the Spin group, right? Then why require that the representation of the Spin group is not restricted from a representation of the whole algebra? Also, it is not clear to me why $(q,v)=(qg,g^{−1}v)$ instead of  $(q,v)=(qg,gv)$. Sorry if these are stupid questions but I am having issues on this specific topic.

As for the second question, this is because, by convention, we act from the right on $P$, but from the left on $V$. There we need to act by the inverse on $V$ to get a group action of $G$ on $P\times V$. Try it without the inverse and see what happens. As for the first question, I'll come back to that later as it's a bit less straightforward.

Okay I found a way to express it succinctly: any representation of $\text{Spin}(p,q)$ that is induced by a representation of $\text{Cl}(p,q)$, must in fact be induced by a representation of $\text{Cl}^0(p,q)$, due to the simple fact that $\text{Spin}(p,q)$ is a subset of the even part. Hence, it suffices to impose this restriction. Nevertheless, the one you are hinting at might be more intuitive to understand, but it would make no difference.

Thank you very much. I found that on this specific topic, the resources I am reading are quite vague and do many things implicitly. If you have time, you may check out the question I just posted, which concerns my last doubt on spinor bundles. Have a nice day.
